# Chord symbols and Pedal markings

Tags: notation

Adding Chord symbols is a great way to simplify reading music and memorizing it. Now I cannot decide if I should or should not put them in all scores. Should I just put it in sazz songs and improv. pieces?

Smaller question: Pedal markings - omitting them saves space, so when should I omit them?

Comment: Certainly in jazz, also in pop and Musicals type pieces. But in a piece such as Bach, Beethoven , Ravel, Grieg, etc. would have written, the harmonies can change so fast, it would be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Where the precise written texture matters, make people read the notes!   Where 'busking' is appropriate, chord symbols can be useful.

But if you want to use them for analysis, fine.

Pedalling?  Vastly over-done, both in notation and performance.  You don't need to be meticulous - a simple 'con pedale' will get you normal legato pedalling.  Anything EXCEPT 'senza pedale' will probably get it anyway!

This sort of pedalling can avoid a load of messy ties.

[image]